# How to deserialize table with multiple lists

Tags: html, vb.net, xml-serialization

I'm having trouble deserializing this table due to the fact of having multiple lists, I understand I need a list for my trs as they repeat, but also for my tds as they also repeat, the problem comes when trying to read the value of the tds, as I have it in a list format.

Here's my xml:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And my classes:

```
Public Class table
    Private newtr As List(Of tr)
    <XmlElement()> _
    Public Property tr() As List(Of tr)
        Get
            Return newtr
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of tr))
            newtr = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class


Public Class tr
    Private newtd As List(Of td)
    <XmlElement()> _
    Public Property td() As List(Of td)
        Get
            Return newtd
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of td))
            newtd = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class


Public Class td
    Private newvalue As String
    <XmlElement()> _
    Public Property td() As String
        Get
            Return newvalue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            newvalue = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And my code:

```
Public Sub test2()
    Dim rr As New table()
    Dim xx As New XmlSerializer(rr.GetType)
    Dim objStreamReader2 As New StreamReader("table.xml")
    Dim rr2 As New table()
    rr2 = xx.Deserialize(objStreamReader2)
    For Each ii As tr In rr2.tr
        MsgBox(ii.td)
    Next
End Sub
```

So any ideas on how could I get each one of the values inside the tds? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have `tr.td` declared as a list, so you can't just output it as a single string.  You would need to loop through each `td` item in the list:

```
For Each currTr As tr In rr2.tr
    For Each currTd As td In currTr.td
        MessageBox.Show(currTd.td)
    Next
Next
```

However, that won't read the values in your example XML properly.  In your example, each `td` element contains a string, not another sub-element by the same name.  But your data structures assume that the structure of the XML looks like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <td>1</td>
  </td>
  <td>
   <td>2</td>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <td>3</td>
  </td>
  <td>
   <td>4</td>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

To fix that, you simply need two classes like this:

```
Public Class table
    Private newtr As List(Of tr)
    <XmlElement()> _
    Public Property tr() As List(Of tr)
        Get
            Return newtr
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of tr))
            newtr = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class


Public Class tr
    Private newtd As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement()> _
    Public Property td() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return newtd
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of String))
            newtd = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Then, you can loop through the deserialized objects like this:

```
For Each currTr As tr In rr2.tr
    For Each currTd As String In currTr.td
        MessageBox.Show(currTd)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Ah!  It's you :)  I didn't recognize you by your numeric value.  I need to update my photo.  I'm afraid it's slightly too disturbing.

Comment: I should fix that, and you look like a programmer, nothing wrong with that. :)